# How to continue ajax remaining requests if file not found?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http-status-code-404, status

I'm trying to script a function which takes all the css/js files marked by `attribute-data` and refreshes if any of the scripts have been modified on the server side. My [initial attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30074807/how-to-refresh-the-pages-cache-if-scripts-have-been-updated) involved php and jquery/javascript. This new attempt is based on javascript/jquery only!

My problem is that while chaining the ajax requests to these files (for Modification date), all ajax requests stop if file not found. For example, if I rename (existing) style.css to (doesn't exist) style_.css, all the chained ajax requests get aborted, and the code doesn't continue.

```
var file_url = [url1, url1, url3, url4, url5];

function getLatestModificationDate(file_url){
    $.when.apply($, file_url.map(function(url) {
        return $.ajax({ type: 'HEAD', url: url, beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) { jqXHR.url = settings.url; } });

    })).done(function() {
        var results = [], lastModified, file_jqXHR; 
        //each argument passed to this callback for ajax, is of this form [data, statusText, jqXHR]
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            var obj= {};
            file_jqXHR = arguments[i][2]; //jqXHR
            lastModified = file_jqXHR.getResponseHeader('Last-Modified');
            obj['file'] = file_jqXHR.url;
            obj['modDate'] = lastModified;

            fileArray.push(obj); 
        }
        mainFunction(fileArray); //the main function, not in scope for this question.
    });
  }
```

I tried adding `error` option in ajax after `beforeSend`, that didn't allow continuing of remaining ajax requests. Don't know if `return ajax apply(.., ..)` 
could return false to skip the current request for `404`, cause I don't know how to skip or return false for the ajax? Is there any quick way to check if the file exists? So that I add only existing files to the `file_url` array that's passed to the `function getLatestModificationDate(file_url){...}`

EDIT: Here's a screenshot from the Chrome-Console.

[image: Ajax Error]

EDIT :

I found [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075074/is-there-a-way-to-continue-after-one-deferred-fails) that uses a new deffered for the ajax complete... could someone provide any simplification on how that code can be used for my question? Thanks!

```
var myDeferred = $.Deferred();
var origDeferred = $.ajax(...);
// if request is ok, i resolve my deferred
origDeferred.done(function() {
  myDeferred.resolve.apply(this, arguments);
});
// if request failed, i also resolve my deferred
origDeferred.fail(function() {
  myDeferred.resolve.apply(this, arguments);
});
```

Comment: were you able to find a solution to this? I am currently stuck here as well! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Try-Catch block:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    try{
            var obj= {};
            file_jqXHR = arguments[i][2]; //jqXHR
            lastModified = file_jqXHR.getResponseHeader('Last-Modified');
            obj['file'] = file_jqXHR.url;
            obj['modDate'] = lastModified;

            fileArray.push(obj); 
    }catch(e){}
}
```

Comment: Nope that doesn't solve it... I've updated my question with an error image from the console...

Comment: Hi! Siamak.. I found [this question's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075074/is-there-a-way-to-continue-after-one-deferred-fails) that uses a new deffered for the ajax complete... could you provide any simplification on how that code can be used for my question? Thanks!